# How to set dynamic layout from app module through viewstub defined in base view of library module?

Tags: android, module, shared-libraries, viewstub

**BaseView of the library module which is not working:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Normal method to inflate the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.base_view_stub_layout);

        viewStub.setLayoutResource(getLayoutId());

        if (!hasStubInflated) {
            View inflatedView = viewStub.inflate();
            //Abstract method to bind inflatedView
            onViewStubInflated(inflatedView, savedInstanceState);
            //Normal method to hide progress bar 
            onViewStubInflated();
        }
    }
```

**BaseView of the library module which is working without *viewStub*:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Normal method to inflate the layout
        setContentView(getLayoutId());
     }
```

**Abstract method that every child view will override:**

```
public abstract int getLayoutId();
```

**Why inflating the dynamic layout without *viewStub* work but not with *viewStub*?**